# Change default Visual Studio behavior for MVC 2 project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've created an MVC 2 project with nested areas, such as:

```
Areas
-->A
   -->C
      --> Controllers
      --> Models
      --> Views
   -->D
      --> Controllers
      --> Models
      --> Views
   -->Controllers
   -->Models
   -->Views
-->B
   -->E
      --> Controllers
      --> Models
      --> Views 
   -->F
      --> Controllers
      --> Models
      --> Views 
   -->Controllers
   -->Models
   -->Views
Controllers
Models
Views
```

This works and correctly finds all the controllers/views as long as I modify the area names in the area registration files to be "A/C" instead of simply "C".  However, the default behavior for Visual Studio is not correct for this project layout.  If I add an action method to a controller inside "A/C/Controllers", right-click and choose "Add View", VS creates the folder and file "A/Views/{controller}/{action}.aspx" instead of "A/C/Views/{controller}/{action}."

Is there a way to change this default behavior?  Perhaps create an add-on that overrides the default behavior?  I'm pretty new to .NET and VS 2010 so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify the structure of your project (what you typed in makes no sense) as well as what behavior you would expect.

Comment: Interesting, I've never even used the Add View.  We've built a 300 view app and always just copy and paste an existing basic template view and modify accordingly.

Comment: So the diagram represents an MVC 2 project with 2 Areas, A and B.  Underneath A are two more areas, C and D, and underneath B are two areas, E and F.

Comment: Let's say I add a Controller called "Home" to the "Controllers" folder in Area "C".  I then add an action method named "List" to this controller.  Currently if I use the VS default for adding a view for this method, it creates a folder called "Home" under the A/Views and an ASPX file called List.aspx under A/Views/Home.  The behavior I want, however, for the "Home" folder to be created under A/C/Views and the corresponding ASPX file added there.

Comment: Jess, thanks for you comment.  I have a feeling I'll simply do the same thing (copy and paste) but I wanted to understand if the default VS behavior was easy to modify first.

Comment: this would be done via route mapping